# Angular 2 - unit testing - "No provider for Token translations" error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular 2 application and i'm using karma and jasmin for unit testing.
I get the following error when i'm running the tests:
"Error: No provider for Token translations!"

this is the component constructor(it's the app component):

```
constructor(private _ccmApiService: CcmApiService,
          private _usersService: UsersService,
          private _foldersService: FoldersService,
          private _hubService: HubService,
          private _router: Router,
          private _navigationService: NavigationService,
          private _translate: TranslateService,
          private _busyLoaderService: BusyLoaderService,
          private _infoModal: InfoModal) {
```

}

it doesn't need to be provided with any service or module similar to what is in the error.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably because one of your injected services is injecting another service (Token translations) which isn't provided in your testing area. have you stubbed all of these injections? because it's highly recommended that when you're unit-testing a component, you stub the injections, otherwise you're testing all of them together. it would go something like this:

```
let someServiceStub= {...};
let otherServiceStub= {...};

beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ...
            ],
            declarations: [
                ...
            ],
            providers: [
                 // override providers from other components and modules 
                {provide: SomeService, useValue: otherServiceStub},
            ]
        })
        // Override component's own provider
            .overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        {provide: OtherService, useValue: someServiceStub }
                    ]
                }
            });
    }
);
```

Comment: but if i prefer using a Spy? shouldn't i be able to without having to go through this hustle? + since when can a class name can be 2 words? and last thing just to be clear - this is the app component constructor - this is just to make sure the app is initializing.

Comment: about  the spy, as you can see in the docs' test guid, it works as this: "This setup is similar to the welcome.component.spec setup. But instead of creating a stubbed service object, it injects the real service (see the testing module providers) and replaces the critical getQuote method with a Jasmine spy" . so the injections of that service would need to be provided too.

Comment: also about the "Token translations" name, i think it's probably related to the use of OpaqueToken(angular2) or InjectionToken(angular4), which puts the word "Token" before the class name inside the error. we have to check the code from other services (i dont know, probably TranslateService) to find the cause of the error. but i think the better way would be stubbing all your services because any time you change any of them, you might get another new error in testing of your AppComponent...

Comment: thanks for the comments, i ended up stubbing the translate service it was pretty simple and it works. i will mark your answer. thanks :)

Comment: exactly! happy to help ;)